# Creating a downloadable PDF file using Blazor C#

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, download, blazor

I'm developing in Blazor C# on .NET 6.0 in Visual Studio, and I need to create a PDF file that the user would be able to download.
The file needs to contain images and Hebrew characters and punctuation from a .tff file, from the link [here](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Assistant).

I tried to create a file via the iTextSharp library on the Server, but the server cannot encode the new font for use, and the default fonts cannot display text in Hebrew.

I then tried to create the file the same way on client-side, since it could have the font embedded, but of course the iTextSharp library can only be used on server-side, as do similar .NET libraries.

My next method was to create a Blazor component that would contain the images and Hebrew text, and use some sort of HTML to PDF conversion, but I can't find a library that performs this conversion, and I also can't pay for external APIs.

Comment: I don't know about Hebrew.  Is it simply alphabetic like English, or does it have special combinations like Korean?

Comment: I'm pretty sure Hebrew has special characters and I think the only way you are going to get that to work in a PDF is to find a Hebrew TTF file, create a base font, and then you use that base font when adding the text to the PDF.

Comment: @Lex sadly I've tried that, and the server cannot create a BaseFont from a Hebrew TTF file, citing an encoding error.

Answer (score 0):

You can try two options, both renders PDF on front end:

1. try to  render your document as html in iframe element and use embedded browser Print dialog where user can select Save to PDF option
   OR
2. Render your document as html in iframe (you can create document html template with needed style then populate to it data using [Handlebars.Net](https://github.com/Handlebars-Net/Handlebars.Net) ),  then convert iframe.body to png using [dom-to-image](https://github.com/tsayen/dom-to-image) and then png convert to pdf using [jsPdf](https://github.com/parallax/jsPDF)

Draft JS code:

```
function generatePdf(htmls) {
    var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
    var iframedoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
    var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm');
    
    var first = true;

    const render = html =>
        new Promise(resolve => {
            iframedoc.body.innerHTML = html;
            if (iframedoc.body.scrollHeight > 1100) {
                iframedoc.querySelector('body').classList.add('body2c')
            } else if (iframedoc.body.scrollHeight > 2200) {
                iframedoc.querySelector('body').classList.add('body3c')
            }
            domtoimage.toPng(iframedoc.body)
                .then(function (dataUrl) {
                    var img = new Image();
                    img.src = dataUrl;
                    if (!first) {
                        doc.addPage();
                    }
                    first = false;
                    doc.addImage(dataUrl, 'PNG', 5, 5);
                    resolve(html);
                }).catch(function (error) {
                    console.error('oops, something went wrong!', error);
                });
        });
    const postrender = async () => {
        for (html of htmls) {
            await render(html);
        }
        if (htmls.isdownload == true) {
            doc.save(htmls.filename ? htmls.filename : "pdfname.pdf");
        } else {
            doc.autoPrint();
            window.open(doc.output('bloburl'), '_blank', "toolbar=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,modal=yes,top=200,left=350,width=800,height=600");
        }
        document.body.removeChild(iframe);
    };
    postrender();

}
```

invoke from c#:

```
string[] htmlDocs = ...
await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("generatePdf", new { Htmls = htmlDocs, isdownload = true, filename = fileName });
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, everyone. I ended up creating a new Blazor component as an HTML page, and added a button that ran the JavaScript function "window.print()", since the user can choose to "Print to PDF" that way.

Comment: Hi Ido,
Please could you share your solution on this answer?  I for one would like to know exactly how you resolved it.
Thank you.